# Grails 2.0 PermGem space with run-war

Tags: tomcat, grails

I've an basic app that working fine when i'm runngin it with `grails run-app`, and I want to run it using `grails run-war`. But i'm always getting famous tomcat's `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGem space` error, on any request, just after start.

Well, I know that I need to change `PermSize` value, so I tried all ways that i've found after googling (`JAVA_OPTS`, `GRAILS_OPTS` and `grails.tomcat.jvmArgs`), and now I have following script:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
grails -Dgrails.tomcat.jvmArgs="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" run-war
```

but it doesn't help. Still having `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` on first request.

What i'm doing wrong? Is there any other way to configure `PermSize` for Grails 2.0.1?

Update: I run `ps -ef | grep java` and found that Grails actually got my params, but then it ran a new process, for tomcat, w/o this params.

Comment: Do you know if the grails process is accepting your params? ps -ef | grep java. Did you to raise it in the underlying tomcat startup.sh?

Comment: Oh, thank you for suggestion, seems that it accepts my params, but just for `grails` command, and it runs second process, for tomcat, w/o such params :(

Comment: OK. Did you try to set grails.tomcat.jvmArgs as a build property?

Comment: Seems to be a solved issue in 1.3.5 http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6346 Maybe it is not ported yet to 2.x. According to this thread http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-run-war-td2535054.html the only solution is to hard code jvm parameter values to tomcat plugin

Comment: Gabe, yes, I have tried `grails -Dgrails.tomcat.jvmArgs="-XX:PermSize=512m"`. Is it correct syntax?

Comment: @enterlezi, hm, it's really weird if it's not in 2.0.1. I'll take a look at current sources

Comment: @gabe, found that I need to configure jvmArgs at BuildConfig, not command line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found that it must be configured at `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs= ["-Xms256m",  "-Xmx1024m", "-XX:PermSize=512m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"]
```

Now it's working fine.

Comment: nice, thats what i meant by "set as build property" ;-)

Comment: yes, I missed it, because I was sure that it must be set at command line, because of nature of such params

Comment: no worries. im happy it works for you. you can +1 my comment if you want to. have fun.

Comment: How do I do this for Grails 2.5.0 and Java 8 and Tomcat 8?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got the correct info with `grails.tomcat.jvmArgs`, for future reference, it's easy to tell what flags a jvm process is running with using 2 commands that come with the JDK.  `jps` shows all processes running with java (easy to find the grails process with this compared ot regular `ps`, and `jinfo <PID>` will dump out all of the system properties and flags for a running JVM process (including the memory args).  It makes it really easy to see whether or not a process is running with all the values you expect it to.